# If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then $cf$ is integrable on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, riemann-integration

"Show that if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then $cf$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, where $c\in \Bbb{R}$"

I think we need to look at $c\geq 0$, and $c\leq 0$ separately. Let $c\geq 0$ and $P$ any partition of $[a,b]$, and let $m_i$ and $m_i'$ be the infima of $f$ and $cf$ on some sub-interval $\Delta x_i$ of $P$. Now $$m_i\leq f \implies cm_i\leq cf$$ $$m_i' \leq cf$$

which means that $cm_i \leq m_i'$ ( where $i=1,...,n$ ). Multiplying by $\Delta x_i$ gives $$c \cdot \Delta x_i m_i\leq\Delta x_i m'_i \implies c\cdot L(P,f)\leq L(P, cf).$$

Similarly, let $M_i$ and $M'_i$ be the suprema of $f$ and $cf$, again on $\Delta x_i$. This now yields $$cM_i \geq M'_i\implies c \cdot \Delta x_iM_i\geq M'_i \Delta x_i \implies c\cdot U(P,f) \geq U(p,cf).$$

Which gives the following inequality $$c\cdot L(P,f) \leq L(P,cf) \leq U(P,cf) \leq c\cdot U(p,f). ( 1)$$

If this is correct, I see this as similar to the proof of the integrability of the sum of two integrable functions. However, I'm not sure what the next step here should be. I think I should maybe use $$c \cdot U(P,f) - c \cdot L(P,f) < c \cdot \epsilon.$$

along with $(1)$. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: $m_i^\prime=c m_i$ and $M_i^\prime=cM_i$....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly let $\epsilon\gt 0$ be given. Then there exists a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that $U(p,f)-L(P,f)\lt\frac{\epsilon}{c}$

Let $c\gt 0\\$ and $\ P$ be that partition of [a,b], and let $m_i\\$ and $m_i^{'}\\$ be the infima of f and cf on some sub-interval $Δx_i\\$ of P.

Now, $\\inf (cf)=c\cdot inf(f)\implies 
 c \cdot \Delta x_iM_i= M'_i \Delta x_i \implies
  c\cdot L(P,f)= L(P,cf) \\ $

Similarly, let $\ M_i\\$ and $\ M_i^{'}\\$ be the suprema of f and cf, again on $\ Δx_i\\$. This now yields $\\cM_i = M'_i\implies c \cdot \Delta x_iM_i= M'_i \Delta x_i \implies c\cdot U(P,f) = U(p,cf).$

Therefore $\\ U(p,cf)-L(P,cf)= c[ U(p,f)-L(P,f)] \lt c\cdot \frac{\epsilon}{c}=\epsilon \\$ for a partition $P$.

Thus being a sufficient condition for integrability, $cf$ is integrable.

When $c\lt0$ it can be proven similarly.
And for $c=0$ $cf(x)=0$ and is integrable.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g = cf$, and suppose that $c\gt0$. Then for any interval $I$, $\sup _I g = c \sup _I f$, $\inf _I g = c \inf _I f$. Therefore $\bar \int g = c \bar \int f$, $\underline{\int} g = c\underline{\int}f$. Therefore $\bar \int g = \underline{\int}g$ and $g$ is integrable.

One can apply a similar argument for $c\lt0$.

If $c=0$, $g(x)=0$, which is obviously integrable.